# Storing or not storing specific line in file on github

Tags: git, security, github

I have various scripts that I would like to make available to several other people to use with their own accounts. I keep these scripts in a github repo.

Let's say I have a bash script to ssh into computer via:

```
username=crzyuser123
ssh -XY $username@specialcomputer.com
```

Now I'm not crazy, I don't store my password (using rsa pub/private keys) in the script, but let's say that it's a very handy script that I use and update all the time, and other people also use all the time (but they clearly have a different **username**).

What I'd like to be able to do is say, "git pull, then edit this one line in the file so that your username is there, then forget it!"  And each time they git pull to update their repo, it leaves that line unchanged.

They could, of course, update this one line every time they update the repo, but that seems to be a huge pain. I also need to convey any solution in not-too-difficult way.

What's the best practice to making this situation easiest for all involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a way to not store the username in the bash script. Here's the bash solution I've implemented:

```
# If an argument is passed, set as supercomputer username
if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
  username=$1
# Else, use the current username as the supercomputer username
else
  username=$LOGNAME
fi
```

This allows for the script to be run automatically (assuming that the current user is the same as the supercomputer username). And if someone needs to enter a different username, the script will take that one.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution

Set up a new account, say "jdoe" on the machine. Put your public key in `/home/jdoe/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and stick the repo (or a clone) wherever would be appropriate. Add the public key of each user that uses your script to the same `authorized_keys` file, and hardcode `jdoe` in the script.

There are cleaner solutions, but this is probably the quickest way to get what you want.

Edit: If it's github you need to grant them access to, you might want to set up an organization or have them generate a key pair for github specifically. Still a matter of adding their pubkeys in the right spot.

Comment: See that becomes tricky. "specialcomputer" is actually one of ~30 computers -- chosen by the script at runtime in a sensible way (as in, each time it's run, it could be any of them). And the script is to log the person in as themselves on that computer, not as jdoe or some other user.

Comment: Well, that changes things. Maybe you could add a file, like "settings.tmpl.sh" that has a spot for their username or whatnot in the file and instructions to fill it in, copy it to "settings.sh" or whatnot, and also put "settings.sh" in .gitignore ... or something like that.

Comment: Uh, I forgot to mention sourcing the settings file in your script.

Comment: yeah I started thinking down this route as well... I think that's basically what I'm going to have to do unless someone comes up with something very clever.

Comment: FWIW, that's a fairly common "user-specific config file in VC" pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is not to store username/passwords in files at all. Pass those values as parameters to your script. Or read them from a config file. But never ever hardcode such things in the first place. Even when it's "only a shell script".

If you pass them as parameter, who ever wants to use your script can either wrap his own script around it that calls your script with the appropriate parameters, or pass the params manually.

With a config file, everyone can have a proper config file which he does not commit to the repo.